# Geometrical bodies whose thickness is independent of their orientation

Tags: geometry

I recently saw or read somewhere of a group of geometrical bodies that share a special property with the sphere: no matter how you rotate them, they have the same "thickness" in all directions. They had a specific name. Does anyone know what I'm referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width

Comment: Or maybe better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_constant_width. Or just type "constant width" into Google; many links appear.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean [spheroforms](http://www.lama.univ-savoie.fr/~lachand/Spheroforms.html)? 
[image]

In a two dimensional plane it is [Reuleaux triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle).

Comment: If you're British, take a hard look at a 50p coin. It has to have constant diameter so that it will work in vending machines, I suppose. There's also an interesting drill bit that can be used for drilling square holes (whose name I have long since forgotten).